# Is there a way to run Okhttps request synchronously?

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

So i am kind of experimenting with an app and i am making an okhttp request. I found out that this request task is made on its own thread, which leads to an asynchronous behaviour.

Down below you see my function which gets the data from the API, and the onCreateView function, where i call fetchData().

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun fetchData() {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a")
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                call.cancel()
            }

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val responseString = U.formatJson(response.body?.string())
                val meals = Gson().fromJson(responseString, Meals::class.java)
                
                Log.d(TAG, "First")
                
            }
        })
    }
```

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        fetchData()

        Log.d(TAG, "second")

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }
```

So i put these logs here to see, which Log gets called first, and since fetchData() is asynchronous, it is obvious that Log.d(TAG, "second"), which is in onCreateView(), gets called first. So if i try to use the data that is getting requested down below, i get null because the request has not yet finished. And that is my problem. I need to use the requested data after calling the function.

Is there any solution where i can do fetchData() somehow synchronous, but without blocking the main Thread?

Comment: you can move this call to onViewCreated and then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: "I need to use the requested data after calling the function" -- `inflater.inflate()` does not need the results of `fetchData()`.

Comment: @a_local_nobody i actually have already tried to do it with a callback, and it works fine. But i can actually only use the data in the override function, which also returns me my response. I need to use the data after the fetchData() call.

Comment: "i can actually only use the data in the override function" which override function? Your response gets some `meals`. What do you do with those meals? You can't run blocking synchronous code on the main thread without risking ANR or `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. It freezes up the device while it's blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a network request on the main thread. It *has* to be asynchronous. Just kind of guessing at what you're doing, I'd add a callback to your fetch function and use it like this.

```
fun fetchData(callback: (Meals?) -> Unit) {
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a")
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            call.cancel()
            callback(null)
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val responseString = U.formatJson(response.body?.string())
            val meals = Gson().fromJson(responseString, Meals::class.java)
            callback(meals)
        }
    })
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    fetchData { meals ->
        if (meals == null) 
            showErrorMessage()
        else
            updateSomeListAdapterWithMeals(meals)
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}
```

Since the callback will fire later, it doesn't matter that you're calling `fetchData` before inflating your view.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Thanks for your answers, i now use the fetched data in the callback function since there is no other useful way. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score -1):

try the following code for synchromized request:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun fetchData() {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a")
            .build()

       Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

       if(response.isSuccessful()){
            val responseString = U.formatJson(response.body?.string())
            val meals = Gson().fromJson(responseString, Meals::class.java)
                
            Log.d(TAG, "First")             
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Request failed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: With this code i get a networkOnMainThreadException. I tried to bypass this exception by running this task in a new thread, but then i got the same problem again.